# Proof of the bilinear analogue of Schauder's theorem

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-theory, compact-operators, bilinear-operator

I am trying to find a proof of the following statement, which is the bilinear analogue of Schauder's theorem for linear operators. I know that this is proved (I think for the first time) in the article ''Operator ideals and spaces of bilinear operators '' by Ramanujan and Schock, but the proof is very densely written making it difficult to follow. Is there a reference where I can find this proof in more detail or can someone give a detailed proof?

*The statement*

Let $A$,$B$ and $E$ be Banach spaces (over $\mathbb{C}$) and let $T: A \times B \rightarrow E$ be a bounded **bilinear** operator. Then, $T$ is a compact bilinear operator if and only if the adjoint operator of $T$, $T^\times:E^* \rightarrow \mathcal{L}(A \times B,\mathbb{C})$ is a compact linear operator.

*Preliminary notions*:

Let $A,B,E$ be normed spaces.

1. A bilinear operator $T:A \times B \rightarrow E$ is called **bounded** if there exists some finite constant $C>0$ such that for all $a \in A$ and $b \in B$, $\|T(a,b)\|_E \leq C \cdot\|a\|_A \cdot \|b\|_B$. We denote by $\boldsymbol{\mathcal{L}(A \times B,E)}$ the set of all bounded bilinear operators $T: A \times B \rightarrow E$.
2. Let $T \in \mathcal{L}(A \times B,E)$. The **adjoint operator** $T^\times$ of $T$ is the linear operator $T^{\times}:E^* \rightarrow \mathcal{L}(A \times B, \mathbb{C})$ defined by the formula $T^\times(f)= f \circ T$.
3. A bilinear operator $T:A \times B \rightarrow E$ is called **compact** if for every bounded $S \subset A \times B$, the closure of $T(S)$ is compact in $E$.

Comment: Not sure if this is what you want, but here's a hopefully helpful link: https://arxiv.org/abs/1010.1298

Comment: @AlexK Thanks but isn't this a proof of the classical Schauder's theorem for **linear** operators ? I want a proof of the **bilinear** analogue of that result.

Comment: Ah, sorry for the misreading.